# How to implement jquery toggle in laravel4.2?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, toggle

1. There are two pages index and task.
2. I am fetching data of task page on index page with the help of ajax
3. How to use toggle on task page so that it should work well after task page gets loaded on index page.
4. I know how to use toggle but in case of ajax where task page is getting loaded on index page I am totally blank.

Till now I have used this script on index page but class(box) and id(himanshu) is on task page which is getting loaded on index page

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".box").on('click',function(){
{
$("#himanshu").slideUp("fast");
}
});
    $(".box").click(function(){
        $("#himanshu").slideDown();
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post some code showcasing your attempts so far.

Comment: @Bogdan I have added my script

Comment: use $("#himanshu").slideToggle("fast"); docs http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/